# Get characters in string at positions [1] and [2]

Tags: javascript

I know that I can get one character of a string by giving `.charAt()` the index position of that character.

But is there any method to which I can give a range (e.g. from position `1` to position `2` ) and get their respective characters?

Comment: Have you tried googling something like "javascript string range"?

Comment: `is there any method ...` - yes there is, hope that helps

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Haha, this is embarrassing. Yes of course I did google it, but very poorly indeed. :)

Comment: A substring is the term you're looking for.  A simple google search will provide you some options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)**.

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 5); //'ello' is the result
```

If you want to get chars, then `split` it and get an array.

```
arr = res.split('') //["e", "l", "l", "o"] is the result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .substr() method
For example :

```
var example = "Hello world!";
console.log(example.substr(0,5);

// Hello
```

The first parameter in this function is the index start and the second parameter is the numbers of characters you want

Comment: But OP didn't want a method that uses index and a length.  OP needs a method that takes two indexes.

Comment: Right, but I did not quite understand the question